# How to copy files from sub directories to one directory

Tags: linux, rsync, mp3, file-search

Hi I have a folder full of music files on an ubuntu server. I am trying to copy all said music files *.mp3/flac to one directory without there subfolders.

I used this command in rsync, which works to a degree, but it doesn't look into sub-folders that contain the wanted files -

```
rsync ~/DIR/sub_dir/sub_dir2/*.mp3 ~/DIR/sub_dir/D+B
```

This works, but only for the *.mp3 files in sub_dir2 and not any subfolders!

Can rsync actually scan in the sub folders to move *.mp3 files to D+B folder?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

#### Can `rsync` actually scan in the sub folders

Use the recurse option:

> `-r`, `--recursive`             recurse into directories

Source: [rsync(1) - Linux man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync)

Comment: Thanks. I've used the -r option , but this doesn't move any files.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this command, run the command in the folder that contains your sub folders and it will scan for mp3/flac files and copy them to the destination folder. If you want to move, then exchange cp for mv.

```bash
find -iname '*.mp3' -exec cp {} ~/Downloads/Destination Directory/ \;
```

Answer (score 0):

it depends on your rsync implementation

```
rsync --include=*.mp3 --exclude=* ~/DIR/sub_dir/sub_dir2/ ~/DIR/sub_dir/D+B
```

try and let me know because many variants may work as well or better

```
rsync --exclude=* --include=*.mp3 ~/DIR/sub_dir/sub_dir2/ ~/DIR/sub_dir/D+B

rsync --exclude=* --include=*/*.mp3 ~/DIR/sub_dir/sub_dir2/ ~/DIR/sub_dir/D+B

rsync --exclude=* --include=**/*.mp3 ~/DIR/sub_dir/sub_dir2/ ~/DIR/sub_dir/D+B
```

Comment: Hi the first 2 I have tried without anything happening. It just tells me that it is skipping sub_dir. Is it suppose to have both exclude and include tags or are you suppose to switch them out?